# extendable class in configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a configuration class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.config")
public class AppConfig {
    private BrickConfig brickConfig;

}
```

Now BrickConfig is the parent class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "brickConfigType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ValueCopyBrickConfig.class, name = "COPY_VALUE")
})
public class BrickConfig {

    private String level;
    private BrickConfigType brickConfigType;


}
```

while ValueCopyBrickConfig is the child class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ValueCopyBrickConfig extends BrickConfig {

    private String copyFrom;
    private String copyTo;

    public ValueCopyBrickConfig() {
        setBrickConfigType(BrickConfigType.COPY_VALUE);
    }
}
```

and following are the contents of my application.yml

```
app:
  config:
    brickConfig:
        copyFrom: standardSize
        copyTo: displaySize
        level: sku
        brickConfigType: COPY_VALUE
```

Problem is when the application boots up i get an instance of BrickConfig rather than ValueCopyBrickConfig.
How can i get the ValueCopyBrickConfig instance ?

Comment: The json stuff doesn't apply when loding configuration. It isn't even JSON that is being loaded but YAML. And nothing json related parsing (especially not provider specific) is being used to load the configuration.

Comment: Any work around ?